# Pagination using Ajax HTML output is breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am adding screenshots, and you can catch the problem.

When I am clicking the next button, the first row, first column is changed, but the first row second column is unchanged in place of that first row, the third column is replaced. Why it is not replacing the first row-second column?

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    jQuery('.next-page').click(
        function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                context: document.body
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                //console.log(data.nextlink);
                //console.log(data.previousLink);
                //console.log(jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td').is('td'));

                posts = data.rows;
                jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(0)').replaceWith(posts[0][0]);
                jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(1)').replaceWith(posts[0][1]);
                for( i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ) {
                    for( j = 0; j < 7; j++ ) {
                        //jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(' + j + ')').replaceWith(posts[i][j]);

                        //console.log(jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(' + j + ')').is('td'));
                        //console.log( i + "  => " + j + "  =>  " + posts[i][j] );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

**Before next button clicked**

[image]

**After next button clicked**

[image]

Comment: Try starting eq() with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @monace19 sorry, but that is not a solution or way to fix it.why it is not working can you give some idea ? You can notice the code, I have putted that for test, that will be a loop in application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.replaceWith()` method removes all data and event handlers associated with the removed nodes. That is why when you replace the first row first column, actually the whole **td** is replaced with `posts[0][0]`. Because of which, when you try to replace the second column, it replaces the **td** with `posts[0][1]` in third column as now there are only two columns left.

So for this instead of `.replaceWith()` use `.html()` to replace the content as shown below:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
jQuery('.next-page').click(
    function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();

        url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            context: document.body
        }).done(function( data ){
            console.log( data );

            //console.log( data.nextlink );
            //console.log( data.previousLink );
            //console.log(jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td').is('td'));
            posts = data.rows;
            jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(0)').html(posts[0][0]);
            jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(1)').html(posts[0][1]);
            for( i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ){
                for( j = 0; j < 7; j++ ){
                   jQuery('.report-table tbody tr:eq('+ i +') td:eq(' + j + ')').html(posts[i][j]);
                    //jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(' + j + ')').replaceWith(posts[i][j]);

                     //console.log(jQuery('.report-table>tbody>tr>td:eq(' + j + ')').is('td'));
                    //console.log( i + "  => " + j + "  =>  " + posts[i][j] );
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

It will replace the contents as you want.

For making the code work for every row, put `tr:eq('+ yourRowIndex +')` for row as well as you are doing with `td`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is really helpful.but as I have mentioned I have commented the loop for test, if I will use the loop it is not working for 2nd row or any other row, can you give some idea, why  next rows are not updated, can you suggest something about that ?